# Customize <select> and <option> elements

Tags: html, css

I have a select element:

```
<div class="select"> 
    <select id="relationship" name="relationship">
        <option value="">one</option>
        <option value="">two</option>
        <option value="">three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.select {
    font-family: 'irregularisregular',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    height: 1.7em;
    margin: 0.15em 0.5em;
    padding: 0 1em;
    width: 40%;
}

.select select {
    -moz-appearance: window;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

When I click on the select, the options appear, but the block doesn't have the same size as the select block. I don't know what to change so the two blocks `<select>` and `<option>` have the same width.

Comment: Where's the markup for `.select`?

Comment: You dont have any elements with the class `select`

Comment: You havent styled the options via CSS

Comment: sorry i forgot the div. I edited

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other CSS that you have, to ensure same width for the select and its options you should add something in the lines of:

```
select, select option {
   width: 200px; /* change as needed */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two block mentioned does have the same width. Its just hat u have padding in your parent div(.select) and no border on 'select' which is making it "look" bigger that's it.